# Dividing sequential column values with a specific data frame cell in R-Updated

Tags: r

**Updated below**

I have a 1000 row and 780 column data frame in the following format -

| E1 | P1 | All1 | E2 | P2 | All2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 200 | 999 | 300 | 400 | 888 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 |

I have to divide every row value (row 2-1000) in E1, P1 and All1 by first row of All1; E2, P2 and All2 by first row of All2 and so on.

The result that I need is (table values only for illustration, i need the actual values) -

| E1 | P1 | All1 | E2 | P2 | All2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5/999 | 6/999 | 7/999 | 8/888 | 9/888 | 10/888 |
| 11/999 | 12/999 | 13/999 | 14/888 | 15/888 | 16/888 |

What function can be used or how to make a loop for this problem?

**Update on the format of data frame**

Column names are in the following pattern -
Origin_Destination_Airline_Class
for example : NYC_LAX_AA_E
All combinations of *Origin_Destination_Airline* have 3 columns each for the classes (E, P, All).

Updated table format

| NYC_LAX_AA_E | NYC_LAX_AA_P | NYC_LAX_AA_All | DNW_SFO_DL_E | DNW_SFO_DL_P | DNW_SFO_DL_All |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 200 | 999 | 300 | 400 | 888 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 |

Result needed:

| NYC_LAX_AA_E | NYC_LAX_AA_P | NYC_LAX_AA_All | DNW_SFO_DL_E | DNW_SFO_DL_P | DNW_SFO_DL_All |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5/999 | 6/999 | 7/999 | 8/888 | 9/888 | 10/888 |
| 11/999 | 12/999 | 13/999 | 14/888 | 15/888 | 16/888 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/)

1. Loop `across` all the columns (`everything()`) in [`summarise`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html)
2. Get the column name - [`cur_column()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/context.html)
3. Replace the substring i.e. all non-digit in the column names with 'All'
4. Use `get` to return the value of that column, subset the `first` -`[1]` element
5. Divide the subset of rows - excluding the first row with 4

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
    summarise(across(everything(), 
     ~ .[-1]/get(str_replace(cur_column(), '\\D+', "All"))[1]))
```

-output

```
       E1          P1        All1          E2         P2       All2
1 0.005005005 0.006006006 0.007007007 0.009009009 0.01013514 0.01126126
2 0.011011011 0.012012012 0.013013013 0.015765766 0.01689189 0.01801802
```

---

Or using `base R` with `split.default` to split the data into `list` of dataset by splitting on the substring of column name - without the non-digits.  Loop over the `list` with `lapply`, divide the data without the first row by the 'All' column first element, and combine the `list` element by `cbind`ing

```
do.call(cbind, unname(lapply(split.default(df1, 
         sub("\\D+", "", names(df1))), function(x) 
         x[-1,]/x[,startsWith(names(x), "All")][1])))
```

-output

```
        E1          P1        All1          E2         P2       All2
2 0.005005005 0.006006006 0.007007007 0.009009009 0.01013514 0.01126126
3 0.011011011 0.012012012 0.013013013 0.015765766 0.01689189 0.01801802
```

---

With the OP's new dataset, we can replace the characters at the end that are not `_` in the column names with 'All' and `get` the value

```
df2 %>%
    summarise(across(everything(),
       ~ .[-1]/get(str_replace(cur_column(), '[^_]+$', 'All'))[1]))
  NYC_LAX_AA_E NYC_LAX_AA_P NYC_LAX_AA_All DNW_SFO_DL_E DNW_SFO_DL_P DNW_SFO_DL_All
1  0.005005005  0.006006006    0.007007007  0.009009009   0.01013514     0.01126126
2  0.011011011  0.012012012    0.013013013  0.015765766   0.01689189     0.01801802
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(E1 = c(100L, 5L, 11L), P1 = c(200L, 6L, 12L), 
    All1 = c(999L, 7L, 13L), E2 = c(300L, 8L, 14L), P2 = c(400L, 
    9L, 15L), All2 = c(888L, 10L, 16L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df2 <- structure(list(NYC_LAX_AA_E = c(100L, 5L, 11L), NYC_LAX_AA_P = c(200L, 
6L, 12L), NYC_LAX_AA_All = c(999L, 7L, 13L), DNW_SFO_DL_E = c(300L, 
8L, 14L), DNW_SFO_DL_P = c(400L, 9L, 15L), DNW_SFO_DL_All = c(888L, 
10L, 16L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works. I made an omission in the original question. The columns names are in the format - (Origin1_Destination1_Carrier1_E, Origin1_Destination1_Carrier1_P, Origin1_Destination1_Carrier1_All) and so forth. For e.g. NYC_LAX_AA_E. All values other than E, P, All are different. Is there a solution for this also?

Comment: Sorry about this

Comment: @GreenFinance Honestly, that pattern means I have to change the code for `str_replace` i.e. here I used `\\D+`. The ones you showed have lots of changes.  It may be better to post a question that mimics the column names or else people starts coding based on the available example

Comment: @GreenFinance If you can update your post with a new example (keeping the old example as well so that I don't have to remove this piece of code), I can update as well.  thanks

Comment: sure , will do that

Comment: @GreenFinance thanks, I updatd the solution